# Can't install PyTorch with CUDA enabled on WSL

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, nvidia

For the last few months, I've been intermittently running into an issue where I can't install PyTorch with CUDA enabled on WSL on Windows 11.

I use a Windows 11 Desktop PC with an RTX 4090 GPU. The Windows installation has WSL installed and enabled, and I run all my Jupyter Notebooks from WSL.

I used the following command from [PyTorch's website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) to install torch:

`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia`

However, when I run the following cell in a Jupyter Notebook, I get a negative response:

```
import torch

cuda_available = torch.cuda.is_available()
if cuda_available:
    print("CUDA is available")
else:
    print("CUDA is not available")
```

`CUDA is not available`

How do I get a CUDA enabled PyTorch version running?

Comment: What does `conda list` or `nvcc --version` yield?

Comment: The first CUDA toolkit version that officially supported 4090 was CUDA 11.8.  While you probably could use a pytorch built against CUDA 11.7, I would definitely not recommend it.  If you decide to move forward on CUDA versions. , make sure whatever driver you have installed on the native windows side is new enough to support whatever CUDA version you are using on the WSL side.  For general recommendation, I usually just suggest "make sure you have the latest driver for your GPU installed."

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up GPU passthrough for WSL. I've done it, but I don't recommend it as it is quite a hassle to set up and maintain.

Here's a very detailed set of [instructions](https://github.com/replicate/cog/blob/main/docs/wsl2/wsl2.md) if you still want to give it a shot.